# Decrease commission value on update only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

Currently I have a Bid model that includes a percentage commission attribute. After a bid has been created users should only be able to decrease their fixed commission on update. What's the best way to achieve this? My current code displays the error if the attribute is either increased or decreased.

```
validate :check_if_commission_percentage_increased, on: :update

def check_if_commission_percentage_increased
  errors.add :base, 'You can only decrease your percentage commission' unless self.commission_percentage > self.commission_percentage
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
validate :method_name, on: :update

def method_name
  if commission_percentage > commission_percentage_was
    errors.add(:base, "error_message")
  end
end
```

The `*_was` method comes from `ActiveModel::Dirty`. The documentation can be found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and the link to the documentation I had no idea about the was method very handy.

Comment: No problem. The link was dnunez24's contribution though so thanks to him.